# Object Oriented project class structure

Tags: java, android, sqlite, oop

I am an novice programmer and I am looking to see if my idea of OO design is on the money or way off.

I have three classes which control data for a basic android app I am playing with. FishingTrip - each instance of which (surprisingly) represents a fishing trip. Fish - each instance of which represents a fish caught and a DatabaseHelper - this controls the insertion of data into an SQLite database.

This is quite a simple program so I could just implement all the data input and output with the DatabaseHelper inside my android activities. However I get the feeling this isn't good OOP.

An alternative would be to have the Fish class have a constructor that takes input variables, with the object instance calling a method to insert it into the database via the DatabaseHelper and another that can instantiate a Fish object by assigning instance variables from accessing the database i.e:

```
public Fish(String species, int size){
       this.species = species;
       this.size = size;
}
public Fish(DatabaseHelper db, int tripID, int fishID){
       //getFish() is a query inside the DatabaseHelper class
       //that returns the row for one fish from one Fishing Trip
       Cursor c = db.getFish(tripID,fishID);           
       this.species = c.getString(0);
       this.size = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(1));
```

Now as each Fish is caught on a Fishing Trip, should I setup the FishingTrip class with its series of methods, then have Fish extend FishingTrip to enforce that relationship?

Just implementing the database transactions in the android activities using my DatabaseHelper class will get the job done, but I feel that doing it this way other way will be a better method if trying to develop larger programs.

(Note: I will implement other data collection such as coordinates so that I can perform analyses between Fish/FishingTrip objects such as distance between catches or time between catches etc.).

Long story short-Is this the right frame of mind for structuring this project?

Thanks.

Comment: OOP is a tool, not a goal. Anyway, I recommend you read [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0321127420).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fish and DatabaseHelper classes should be decoupled in my opinion. The Fish class is part of your model whereas the DatabaseHelper class is responsible for DB access. Hence, changes to the DatabaseHelper class should not have any impact to Fish. Instead, there should be a layer in between which transfers the data from DatabaseHelper to Fish.

So, instead of:

```
DatabaseHelper db = ...;
int tripID = ...;
int fishID = ...;
Fish fish = new Fish(db, tripID, fishID);
```

you would have:

```
DatabaseHelper db = ...;
int tripID = ...;
int fishID = ...;
Cursor c = db.getFish(tripID, fishID);           
String species = c.getString(0);
int size = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(1));
Fish fish = new Fish(species, size);
```

By doing this, neither class is aware of each other and changes to either class will only affect the mapping layer in the middle.